# Preguntar si quieren volver al menú o salir (Ciclo While) Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, condiciones, while, menu

Estoy intentando imitar la funcionalidad de un cajero automatico. De momento llevo esto, pero necesito agregar un loop que me permita despues de cada opcion preguntar "Deseas realizar otra acción (Y/N)"y dependiendo de esto volver a mostrar el menú o no, ya que, tal cual está hasta ahora, vuelve automaticamente luego de realizar la accion.

*(No me spoileen mas alla del loop que necesito por favor, que mientras voy aprendiendo quiero ir rellenando este codigo).

```
#MENU
saldo = 100000

continuar = True
while continuar:
    menu = int(input('''\n
===============================================
Cajero Automatico
===============================================

1.- Ingresar dinero.
2.- Retirar dinero.
3.- Mostrar saldo.
4.- Salir

Seleccione la opcion que desea: '''))

    #DEPOSITAR
    if menu == 1:
        x = int(input("\nCuanto dinero desea ingresar: $"))
        saldo = saldo + x
        print(f"Su saldo queda en ${saldo}.")

    #RETIRAR
    elif menu == 2:
        x = int(input("\nCuanto dinero desea retirar: $"))
        if x % 5000 == 0:
            if x == 0:
                print("No puede retirar $0.")
            elif x > saldo or x < 0:
                print (f"Ingrese un retiro valido, su saldo es de ${saldo}.")
            elif x <= saldo or x > 0:
                saldo -= x
                print(f"Usted ha retirado: ${x}.")                    
                print(f"Su saldo queda en ${saldo}.")
        else:
            print("Este cajero solo entrega billetes multiplos de 5.")

    #SALDO
    elif menu == 3:
        print (f"\nSu saldo es de: ${saldo}.")

    #SALIR
    elif menu == 4:
        print ("\nGracias por usar este cajero.")
        continuar = False

    #OTROS
    else:
        print("\nOpcion no encontrada.")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu ciclo principal se ejecuta mientras que la variable `continue` sea `True`. Tu ciclo se vuelve a ejecutar automáticamente debido a que después de realizar alguna acción ya no hay mas código (dentro del ciclo). Si lo que pretendes es preguntar al usuario al final de cada operación si quiere volver al menú entonces agrega las siguientes líneas al final de tu bucle:

```
    if menu != 4:
        resp = input('¿Desea volverl al menu? ')
        if resp == 'Y' or resp == 'y':
            pass
        else:
            continuar = False
```

La primera condición `if menu != 4` se asegura de que la opción ingresada por el usuario no haya sido la 4, pues es irónico que elijas la opción salir y te pregunte de nuevo. Una vez se haya cumplido esta condición entonces te pregunta, si no deseas continuar  entonces la variable `continue` se vuelva `False` y ya no se cumple la condición del ciclo principal

Comment: Era justo lo que estaba buscando, gracias Edher! :D